# How to get all PowerPoint files from Skydrive?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, powerpoint, live-sdk

I'm trying to build a windows 8 metro app in C# which shows all PowerPoint Presentations in your SkyDrive Folder. Therefore I'm using the Windows Live SDK.

To get the information about all PowerPoint Files in the users SkyDrive folders I already tried to search for the ppt and pptx extension recursively in all folders, which is kind of a hassle.

Is there a more elegant way to find all PowerPoint Files? In addition to that, I'm trying to show the Presentation in a WebView using the PowerPoint online app, is there an way to get the right URL without building it myself?

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the www I found a "change log" article about the improvements made to the SkyDrive API which announced a search feature.

After playing around with this REST interface, I tried using it for specific file types such as .ppt.
My first results seem to get me what I want, but no guarantee that this is the best solution. It's just the easiest right now!

Here's the C# Code I'm using to get all ".ppt" files through the SkyDrive Search API

```
            LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(App.Session);
            LiveOperationResult liveOperationResult = await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/search?q=.ppt");
            dynamic searchResult = liveOperationResult.Result;
```

Feel free to comment if you find a better solution!